# Compare annotations in Django ORM filter

Tags: django, orm

I'm trying to translate this query into a Django ORM call.

Model:

```
class model(models.Model):
    member = CharField()
    pos = IntField()
```

Query

```
SELECT member
FROM model
GROUP BY member
HAVING MIN(pos) = MAX(pos);
```

What I'm trying:

```
q = model.objects.all()

q.annotate(min=Min('pos'), max=Max('pos')).values('member','pos').filter(min=max)
```

This almost works, if it wasn't for the last call to `.filter(min=max)`. Apparently, I'm not allowed to compare 2 annotations this way.

> TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a
>   number, not 'builtin_function_or_method'

Is this possible in any other way?

EDIT: no, this doesn't almost works. It's completely wrong...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```py
from django.db.models import F, Min, Max

q = model.objects.values('member') \
    .annotate(min_pos=Min('pos'), max_pos=Max('pos')) \
    .filter(min_pos=F('max_pos')) \
    .values('member')
```

Here I use `min_pos` and `max_pos` instead of `min`, `max` since they are the built-in functions of python.

Comment: I had to add `.order_by()` at the beginning since my model meta has ordering and that somehow messes up your solution. Otherwise, it works perfectly!